# How to use dynamic date in mapping of a REST dataset to SQL dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

I get some data from Elasticsearch (via REST Dataset) and add it to a SQL Server Table. I want to add the acutal date via utcnow() to the datasets written to the SQL DB.

I´ve tried to add with @formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-2), 'yyyy-MM-dd') in the field but this leads to "null" in the target database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to say that your syntax for `formatDateTime` is correct. Per my understanding of your requirements,you want to add one more additional column (named nowDate)which is not involved by source dataset.I'm afraid that it is error condition which is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping):

- Source data store query result does not have a column name that is
  specified in the input dataset "structure" section.
- Sink data store (if with pre-defined schema) does not have a column
  name that is specified in the output dataset "structure" section.
- Either fewer columns or more columns in the "structure" of sink
  dataset than specified in the mapping.
- Duplicate mapping.

However, since your sink is sql server,you could add column in stored procedure which could be executed in the copy activity.Please refer to this guide:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#invoke-a-stored-procedure-from-a-sql-sink

Comment: Hi Jay! Thanks for your answer. I think we will go with the stored procedure workaround :)